# simple inequality for probability

Tags: probability, inequality

Let 0$\le p_1,p_2 \le 1$, prove $p_1 + p_2 -2p_1p_2 \le 1$

Seems Cauchy inequality not works. Any feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

No need for heavy machinery like Cauchy-Schwarz.
$$
p_1 + p_2 -2p_1p_2 = 1 - p_1 p_2 - (1-p_1)(1-p_2) \le 1
$$
for $\le p_1,p_2 \le 1$.

You can also argue that
$$
f(p1, p_2) = p_1 + p_2 -2p_1p_2
$$
is linear in both arguments, and therefore the maximum on $[0, 1]^2$ is attained at one of the corner points.

Comment: Thank you both solutions! I can understand the first one but the second is confusing for me. Why linearity will lead to the extreme values existing at four corners?

Comment: @YHC: For fixed $p_1$ is $p_2 \mapsto f(p1, p_2)$ a linear function on an interval, and attains its maximum at one of the boundary points, so that $f(p_1, p_2) \le \max(f(p_1, 0), f(p_1, 1)$. Then repeat the same argument for $p_1 \mapsto f(p_1, 0)$ and $p_1 \mapsto f(p_1, 1)$. – This is a special case of the fact that a convex function attains its maximum on a convex set at one of the extreme points.

Answer (score 1):

If $p_1=P(A)$ and $p_2=P(B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are independent events then $p_1+p_2-2p_1p_2$ can be recognized as $P(A\Delta B)$.

Observe that: $$\mathbf1_{A\Delta B}=\mathbf1_A+\mathbf1_B-2\mathbf1_A\mathbf1_B$$

Comment: Thanks for such intuitive idea. Brilliant observation.

Comment: @YHC You are very welcome. Actually this proves the inequality by *making use* of probability theory.